# BeginForm in RC bug?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I think that there is something wrong with the new RC. When I write

```
Html.BeginForm("Item", "Newsletter", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

method must render in output something like this:

```
<form action="/Newsletter/Item" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

but instead of that I'm getting:

```
<form action="Item" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Where is my full action path?

Comment: Check your routes. I think I ran into this before when I changed the default route and it fell through to the catchall.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this everywhere, or just when you are viewing other action results of the "Newsletter" controller?  If it is the latter, this behavior is working as intended.

There is no need for an absolute path if you are e.g. currently navigated to **`http://yourwebsite.com/newsletter/`**.  In that case a relative path of **`item`** would take you to **`http://yourwebsite.com/newsletter/item/`**.